# Find minimum value of $7(a^4+b^4+c^4)+\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a}$

Tags: inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $a+b+c=3$. Find minimum value of $$7(a^4+b^4+c^4)+\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a}$$

I tried to use $(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)\geq3(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)$, but without success.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Without showing effort, you most likely won't get help.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward, they're all positive numbers and have to sum to $3$, so $a=b=c=1$, then just plug and solve...unless I'm missing something here and $0$ is permitted in the set $\mathbb{R}^+$, which I don't think is the case.

Comment: i think it is $22$ for $a=b=c=1$

Comment: @Ben why do you think min is at $a=b=c=1$?

Comment: @Χpẘ The condition requiring $a+b+c=3$ while we also have that $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^+$ would make $a=b=c=1$ true

Comment: @Ben yes but it doesn't necessarily represent min

Comment: $(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)\geq 3(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)$

Comment: In terms of showing effort you should edit the OP, not add comments.

Comment: İ don't think The Cauchy-Schwarz is correct shouldn't it be $(ab+bc+ac)(a+b+c) \geq (a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea works!
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)\geq3(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)$$ it's
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-2a^2b+a^2c)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-2a^2b+ab^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}a(a-b)^2\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Thus, $$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\leq a^2+b^2+c^2.$$

Now, for $a=b=c=1$ we get a value $22$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, by your lemma it's enough to prove that
$$7(a^4+b^4+c^4)+\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\geq22.$$
By AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}(a^4+3)\geq\sum_{cyc}4\sqrt[4]{a^4\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1}=4(a+b+c)=12.$$
Thus, $$a^4+b^4+c^4\geq3.$$
Also, by AM-GM again we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4+1)\geq\sum_{cyc}2\sqrt{a^4\cdot1}=2(a^2+b^2+c^2).$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\geq4$$ or
$$\frac{9(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{(a+b+c)^2}+\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\geq4.$$
Let $a^2+b^2+c^2=k(ab+ac+bc).$

Thus, $k\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$\frac{9k}{k+2}+\frac{1}{k}\geq4$$ or
$$(k-1)(5k-2)\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Done!